# how to check badsector on ext4 6TB

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, badblocks

how to check bad sector on HDD 6TB

```
koko@Rumah:~$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda2
[sudo] password for koko: 
badblocks: Value too large for defined data type invalid end block (5751976960): must be 32-bit value
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152171/badblocks-only-takes-32-bit-integer-as-start-end-values

Comment: that not help at all :( any specific solution for ubuntu x64 14.04?

Comment: I read that link and it looks like it's definitely specific to this.

Comment: Ivan, the link mentioned explains that `badblocks` can't cope with HDDs that large. You'll not get it to run on your 6TB HDD, no matter what you'll do.

Comment: ok so if 6 TB HDD, what should i do ? or make partition 2 tb? or 1tb?

Answer (score 71):

for me the trick was to simply increase the blocksize:

```
badblocks -b 4096 -v /dev/sda
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for my 10TB drive.  Hopefully for my 16TB drive soon

Comment: Didn't work with my 18 (in fact, 16+) Tb HDD :(

Comment: @PocketSam that's because `4096 x (2^32) = 17592186044416`, or 16 TiB. Your 18 TB disk (18,000,000,000,000 bytes) is 16.37 TiB, so 0.37 TiB too large for 4096 byte blocks at 32-bit. You'll need a larger block size, e.g. 8192 bytes, though I'm not sure what exact size is ideal to use beyond 4096.